# How to parse JSON object with Gson to map of unknown type

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit

I'm starting to use Gson with Retrofit, rather than Jackson, to parse some Json from a Wikipedia API that's structured like this:

```
{
  "batchcomplete": "",
  "query": {
    "pages": {
      "21721040": {
        "pageid": 21721040,
        "ns": 0,
        "title": "Stack Overflow",
        "extract": "Stack Overflow
```

Within the "pages" object, I'm trying to map the next block to a Map object of key/value type String and WikiSummary, but the object returns null. Through Jackson, if I remember correctly, you could do direct mapping like this, since I don't know the object values that "pages" has within it.

**WikiPages.class**

```
public class WikiPages {

    public Map<String, WikiSummary> summaryMap;

    public WikiPages(Map<String, WikiSummary> summaryMap) {
        this.summaryMap = summaryMap;
    }

    public Map<String, WikiSummary> getSummaryMap() {
        return summaryMap;
    }

    public void setSummaryMap(Map<String, WikiSummary> summaryMap) {
        this.summaryMap = summaryMap;
    }

}
```

**WikiSummary**

```
public class WikiSummary {

    public int pageid;
    public String title;
    public String extract;

    public WikiSummary(int pageid, String title, String extract) {
        this.pageid = pageid;
        this.title = title;
        this.extract = extract;
    }

    public int getPageid() {
        return pageid;
    }

    public void setPageid(int pageid) {
        this.pageid = pageid;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getExtract() {
        return extract;
    }

    public void setExtract(String extract) {
        this.extract = extract;
    }
}
```

Comment: since your json properties are dynamic, the easiest solution would be to make pages a HashMap<String, WikiSummary>. Gson can parse that just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem just not to need `WikiPages` since it must be a map itself (for the simplest Gson configuration; otherwise a more complex deserializer is necessary). Therefore Gson is looking for the `summaryMap` property that is not present in the given JSON, and that's why it's `null`. The following mappings

```
final class WikiResponse {
    @SerializedName("batchcomplete")
    final String batchComplete = null;
    @SerializedName("query")
    final WikiQuery query = null; // this is what you seem to be looking for
}

final class WikiQuery {
    @SerializedName("pages")
    final Map<String, WikiSummary> pages = null;
}

final class WikiSummary {
    @SerializedName("pageid")
    final int pageId = Integer.valueOf(0); // can't be null, but a simple `0` literal will be inlined
    @SerializedName("title")
    final String title = null;
    @SerializedName("extract")
    final String extract = null;
}
```

can represent the JSON (assuming the DTOs above are incoming and not designed as outgoing [otherwise enhanced]; and Gson can assign real values to final fields). Parsing the given JSON and querying the deserialized POJO with `wikiResponse.query.pages.get("21721040").title` will result in `Stack Overflow`.

Comment: Fantastic! That worked. I was wanting to make a Map out of my WikiSummary content, rather than the "pages" object.

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONObject pagesObject = queryObject.getJSONObject("pages");
Set<String> keys = pagesObject.keySet();
for (String k : keys) {
    JSONObject desiredKeyValues = elements.getJSONObject(k);
}
```

Comment: Please could you add some details with your answer? Thanks